# How do I bisect a gap of an stl mesh?

Tags: mesh, error, stl, bisect

As the question asks, how do I bisect or cut a mesh of a gap? This is because I want to use a certain element in an stl file I downloaded online. [image]

I am getting an error which asks for me to select an edge, but I want to bisect the gap. Alternative methods?

Comment: to be able to bisect you need to select at least 2 vertices

Comment: how could i split the stl file then? I want to split the mesh between the gap.

Comment: do you mean you want to separate the meshes? in that case select the mesh you want to separate with L, then press P to separate

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "cut a mesh of a gap", maybe precise what you want